# Avoid persisting prompt in nested selection

Tags: bash

With this bash script the user should select a directory and depending on that doing a second selection of the subdirectories.

```
doSomething() {
    echo "finish"
}

PS3="Select project: "
options=( )
for n in ./apps/*/; do
    options+=("$(basename "$n")")
done
select app in "${options[@]}"; do
    PS3="Select application: "
    options=()
    for n in ./apps/$app/*/; do
        appName=$(basename "$n")
        if [[ "$appName" != *-e2e ]]; then
            options+=("$appName")
        fi
    done
    select project in "${options[@]}"; do
        doSomething $app $project
        break
    done
done
```

My problem is, that the prompt `Select application` keeps active even after the second selection. What am I missing?

Comment: sooo reset it bash? On the end `... break done PS3="Select project: " done`

Comment: Using `break 2` should work

Comment: You want to select the user the subdirectory AFTER selecting the main directory, but you have the loop for selecting the subdirectory INSIDE the loop for selecting the main directory. The program structure does not reflect what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally tend to flatten the logic, because breaking free of nested loops isn't very common:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob extglob

doSomething() { echo "finish"; }

PS3="Select project: "

options=( ./app/*/ )
options=( "${options[@]%/}" )
options=( "${options[@]##*/}" )

select app in "${options[@]}"
do
    [[ -n "$app" ]] && break
done

PS3="Select application: "

options=( ./app/"$app"/!(*-e2e)/ )
options=( "${options[@]%/}" )
options=( "${options[@]##*/}" )

select project in "${options[@]}"
do
    [[ -n "$project" ]] && break
done

doSomething "$app" "$project"
```

**notes:**

- I set `shopt -s nullglob` so that unmatched globs don't expand to anything.
- I'm using two bash Parameter Expansions for getting rid of the trailing `/` & the path prefix of each element in the `options` array.
- I set `shopt -s extglob` for using the glob negation `!(*-e2e)`.

**aside:** I'm not sure why you use `PS3` instead of a simple `echo`, is there a reason for it?

Comment: No specific reason. I'm new to bash and this was why I thought I should use PS3: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-take-control-of-ps1-ps2-ps3-ps4-and-prompt_command/

Comment: **_PS3 – Prompt used by “select” inside shell script_** In fact it makes sense to use that, I didn't know ;-)